# Open new tab in Electron/Angular4 application with a route

Tags: angular, electron

I'm trying to find a way to open a new tab, in an electron/angular application, using a defined route. I build the angular application with the command `ng build --base-href ./` and launch the electron app with the command `electron dist`, where I put the `main.js` and `package.json` link to the electron app. I configure electron to use the `file://` protocol.

I have these routes

- `/`: home route/component where I display all assets
- `/watch`: video player route/component

In my application, when I click on an asset I need to open a new window with the video player. The data is passed using a service. I have used this `window.open('/watch?id=my-id', '_blank')` but it is not working well. I can't use `routerLink` directive because I need to pass data to the player and I use a service for that.

Each time I try to open the new tab, I keep getting a blank new window with an error in the console `couldn't load file:///watch?id=my-id`

So how I can make the Angular router work with the `file://` protocol in a new window?

It works when it's not an electron app, using Chrome with `http://` protocol.

Thank you.

Comment: You can likely use hash strategy, so it will be `/#/watch?id=my-id`

Comment: Already tried to use hash strategy. I keep getting this error `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///#/watch?id=224641`

Comment: Probably should be `index.html#/watch?id=my-id` then. I have no Electron project at hand to test this.

Comment: Didn't work. I don't know if it is possible to do that. I'm asking that because I think that when opening a new window the angular application needs to be loaded again and after navigating to the selected route with all options and parameters.

Comment: Was there an error with index.html#/watch?id=my-id? Is entry point is index.html in root? Probably a new window should be opened with BrowserWindow and `win.loadURL('file://index.html')`, like is shown here https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/

Comment: Already in my `main.js`. You can see `win.loadURL(url.format({ pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'), protocol: 'file', slashes: true }));`

Comment: You likely need to open a window this way, too, not with window.open, like https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#modal-windows